# accessing a nearly-readonly-shared-list Asynchronously

Tags: shared, synchronized, readonly-collection

```
public class PlanetInfo {
    String planetName="";
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    PlanetInfo(planetname){
        planetName = planetname;
        if(planetName.equals("earth")){
            a=1;
            //....
        }
        else if(planetName.equals("mars")){
            a=2;
            //....
        }
    }       
}

public final class Infos {
    static final LinkedList<PlanetInfo> planets = new LinkedList<PlanetInfo>();

    private static synchronized PlanetInfo internal_getPlanetInfo(String planetName){
        for(int i=0;i<planets.size();i++){
            if(planets.get(i).planetName.equals(planetName)){
                //return existing PlanetInfo:
                return planets.get(i);
            }
        }

        //if not found then create and return a new one:
        return new PlanetInfo(planetName);

    }

    public static PlanetInfo getPlanetInfo(String planetName){
        return internal_getPlanetInfo(planetName);
    }
}


public class Foo {    
    PlanetInfo planetinfo = null;
    public Foo(aplanet){
        planetInfo = Infos.getPlanetInfo(aplanet);
    }

    public void dosomthing(){
        if(planetInfo.a==1){//please, do not wonder about thread-safe here, it's just a simplification...
            // etc....
        }
    }


}
```

it is vary rare that a new `PlanetInfo` need to be created, but it happens. once a `PlanetInfo` created and 
added to `Infos.planets`, **IT WILL NEVER BE REMOVED**.
most of the time, `Infos.planets` is practically read-only.

there are many many threads that have instance of `Foo`, they all need a pointer to a `PlanetInfo` object.
as you can see, `internal_getPlanetInfo` is synchronized.

i wonder if i can change the code, so it may do **2** attempts to find the desired `PlanetInfo`. the first
attempt would be **Asynchronously**, and (if not found then do) the second **synchronously**.
so... the mothod `getPlanetInfo` will do the vary same for-loop as method `internal_getPlanetInfo`.
thus, most of the time threads will not lock each other.

the thing i have in mind is that a thread may have a "stale"-copy of `Infos.planets`, **but!** the only potential problem with this "stale"-copy is that it misses an item that was added some time later. so if the desired item not found then we look for it using the **"master"**-copy.

```
public static PlanetInfo getPlanetInfo(String planetName){
    //try to find it Asynchronously:
    for(int i=0;i<planets.size();i++){
        if(planets.get(i).planetName.equals(planetName)){
            return planets.get(i);
        }
    }
    //if not found then do it synchronously:
    return internal_getPlanetInfo(planetName);
}
```

any comments would be appreciated!

ido.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is actually an excellent idea especially in the context of a high level of concurrency. 
The below pattern will ensures that "value" gets computed only once and that the critical section gets executed 
a minimum number of times. In a language-neutral pseudo code the pattern is as follows:

```
if value is-not-available then
    // Entering critical section
    if value is-not-available then
        value = comupte-the-value
    // Exit critical section.
}
return value;
```

I would suggest, if its not already the case, that PlanetInfo objects be immutable and that when their information does change then you need only create a new object with the changed values. Read-only objects avoid lots of concurrency issues.

The staleness issue can be easily be solved with an additional level of indirection. Instead Foo holding on to a PlanetInfo reference they should keep a planetInfoIndex (into Info.planets). When new information is known about the planet then the reference at that index is replaced with a new immutable object. The next time any Foo objects accesses the info the new object will be returned.